# User defined type not defined when creating Outlook Object

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As MailItem
Dim oMail As String
Dim strbody As String
Dim fdatum As String
Dim VorschauBereich As Range
Dim Tabnr As Integer
Dim Tabtext As String
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(oIMailItem)
```

I get the error named in the title and cursor jumps to Dim Dim oApp As Outlook.Application

Comment: I use Office 2016

Answer (score 4):

To solve this, you can either use early binding by adding the Mircrosoft Object Library in your references (from the tools menu). Or you can use Late binding by changing the Outlook object declaration to this:

```
Dim oApp As Object
Dim oMail As Object
```

and then creating the objects like this:

```
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)
```

Depending on whether or not your excel WB is used by other people, I prefer late binding to avoid any issues with references on other people's machines. The downside of late binding is that you don't get inteli-text help while coding. Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you, I can live with that :-) Everything works fine now

Comment: @RWatermelon -Glad to help. Will you accept this answer?

Comment: Sorry no... I still receive that error... Do I have to add the Microsoft Object Library by early binding? Its activated now....

Comment: @RWatermelon If you use early binding then yes, you do need ti add the appropriate library reference

Answer (score 3):

Tools, References, Available References.

Locate and check Microsoft Outlook xx.x Object Library.

[image]