# Importing Outlook Emails to Excel VBA- Error

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have went into tools and referenced but still get this error. How can I get rid of this error?
[image]

Comment: What did you add a reference to?

Comment: Please copy code and error, instead of uploading an image.  Or, show the image, not a link to the image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User defined type not defined when creating Outlook Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798486/user-defined-type-not-defined-when-creating-outlook-object)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have selected the following references in Outlook:

[image]

Comment: Reference in Excel not Outlook. Outlook Object Library instead of Office Object Library

Comment: The same set of references should be checked + Excel one.